# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, casting

I'm trying to pass few ViewModels to the same View via ViewData. Unfortunately I'm new to MVC and I do not have idea what's wrong with that.
Here is first DataViewModel:

```
public class TagsViewModel
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }
}
```

And another one:

```
public class ShortPostViewModel
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string PostSubject { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PostCreated { get; set; }
    public string PostImage { get; set; }
    public string PostAuthor { get; set; }
    public byte? PostRating { get; set; }
    public List<PostTagsViewModel> PostedTags { get; set; }
}
```

Here is repository:

```
public IEnumerable<BlogPostViewModel.ShortPostViewModel> GetLast20()
{
    var last = from a in _db.blog_post
               orderby a.Posted descending
               select new BlogPostViewModel.ShortPostViewModel
               {
                   PostId = a.ID,
                   PostAuthor = (from u in _db.users where u.ID == a.Author 
                                 select u.Login).FirstOrDefault(),
                   PostCreated = a.Posted,
                   PostImage = a.PostAvatar,
                   PostRating = a.Rating,
                   PostSubject = a.Subject,
                   PostedTags = (from b in _db.tags
                                join c in _db.posted_tags on b.ID equals c.TagID
                                where c.PostID == a.ID
                                select new PostTagsViewModel 
                                { 
                                    TagId = b.ID, 
                                    TagName = b.TagName
                                }).ToList()
               };
    return last.Take(20);
}
```

And one more:

```
public IEnumerable<TagsViewModel> GetAll()
{
    var t = from a in _db.tags
        select new TagsViewModel
        {
            TagId = a.ID,
            TagName = a.TagName
        };
    return t;
}
```

So here is Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["ShortPost"] = _postRepository.GetLast20().AsEnumerable();
    ViewData["Tags"] = _tagsRepository.GetAll().AsEnumerable();
    return View();
}
```

So on the View:

```
    <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<ShortPostViewModel>)ViewData["ShortPost"])
        {
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <img src="@item.PostImage" alt=""/>
                <h3>@Html.ActionLink(@item.PostSubject, "Details", "BlogPost", new { id = item.PostId }, null)</h3>
                Создано: @item.PostCreated. Автор: @item.PostAuthor. Оценка: @item.PostRating.
                <p>
                    Темы статьи:
                    @foreach (var tag in @item.PostedTags)
                    {
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i> @Html.ActionLink(@tag.TagName, "Tag", "Search", new { id = tag.TagId }, null)
                    }
                </p>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    @foreach (var tag in (IEnumerable<TagsViewModel>)ViewData["Tags"])
    {
        <span class="label label-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i> @Html.ActionLink(@tag.TagName, "Tag", "Search", new { id = tag.TagId }, null)</span>
    }
</div>
```

This all look just fine for me. Could you advise how should I fix that?

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: This one @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<ShortPostViewModel>) ViewData["ShortPost"]) but I suppose another one as well.

Comment: How about `ViewData["ShortPost"] = _postRepository.GetLast20().ToList();`?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using several `ViewData`, I would recommend using a new ViewModel class that have a `List<TagsViewModel>` property and a `List<ShortPostViewModel>` property so you don't have to do the conversions in the view. Let's say the ViewModel is named `CustomViewModel`

```
public class CustomViewModel
{
    public CustomViewModel()
    {
        this.ShortPosts = new List<ShortPostViewModel>();
        this.Tags = new List<TagsViewModel>();
    }

    public List<ShortPostViewModel> ShortPosts { get; set; }
    public List<TagsViewModel> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

then in your controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    CustomViewModel model = new CustomViewModel();
    model.ShortPosts = _postRepository.GetLast20().ToList();
    model.Tags = _tagsRepository.GetAll().ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

Make sure you have this at the top of your view code

```
@model CustomViewModel
```

You can enumerate the items of `ShortPosts` in your view as below

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ShortPosts)
```

and enumerate the items of `Tags` as below

```
@foreach (var tag in Model.Tags)
```

Comment: thanks, let me try. By the way, as I understand such structure now allow to perform CRUD operations, right?

Comment: Yes you're right, you can ask a new question if you have a problem regarding that.